# Log4j2 not logging to file

Tags: java, xml, log4j2

I'm using Log4j2 in my application and it seems to load and initialize fine.
Console gets logged to, the 2 specified file appenders create their respective files, but those files stay empty!

Is my config faulty? Did I start Log4j2 the wrong way?

Here's the config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="TRACE">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="file" fileName="${sys:logdir}ftm.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
        <File name="file_error" fileName="${sys:logdir}ftm_error.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="file" level="ALL"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="ALL"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="FTM" level="ALL" additivity="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="file_error" level="ERROR"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And here's the code:

```
LoggerContext contextLogging = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);

File file = new File("log4j2.xml");
if (file != null && file.isFile() && file.canRead()){
    contextLogging.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
}
```

I start logging at various points throughout the application after this initialization bit.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your call to obtain the LoggerContext is causing Log4j to initialize. You should see a message saying the default configuration is being used. Why not just use one of the Configurator.initialize() methods?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem. It's an issue in reconfiguration.
Probably a bug in log4j code.

I change

```
System.setProperty("myapp.log.dir", "/tmp/myapp");
URL logres = App.class.getClassLoader().getResource("log4j2_myapp.xml");
LoggerContext.getContext().setConfigLocation(logres.toURI());
```

in

```
System.setProperty("myapp.log.dir", "/tmp/myapp");
URL logres = App.class.getClassLoader().getResource("log4j2_myapp.xml");
Configurator.initialize("myapp", App.class.getClassLoader(), logres.toURI());
```

and all work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe LOG4J2 is buffering your log messages and will write them later.
Have you tried shutting down your app server?
This will force any buffered messages to be written to the file.

Comment: Is there a way one can force this behaviour? Because just shutting down the application does not trigger that.

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry.  I tried your XML config in my web app and it works for me, it's just the writes to the file don't occur until I shut down the web app. My setup is different in a few ways. I used a hard coded file path `/usr/tmp/tmp.log` instead of the variable that you used `${sys:logdir}my.log`. Also, I use Spring which initializes Log4j2 for me, so I don't have your Java code for config.

Comment: Another thing you can check is there is a section in the Log4j2 docs (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html) that explains the config for servlet 3.0 and 2.*. They are slightly different, so double check that. I hope that helps.

Comment: I'm also using Spring but I'm not explicitly using Spring to configure Log4j2. is that maybe why the application is happily logging to console (through Spring) but not to file?

How would I go about making Spring shake hands with Log4j2? FYI: I'm not using Maven.

Comment: After I reviewed the LOG4J2 users guide again, it seems that Spring isn't involved in the init. If your web app is servlet 3.0 and you have LOG4j2's log4j-web.jar on your class path, log4j2 auto initializes. You need to have your log4j2.xml file on the classpath also. I use Maven, so I have it at src/main/resources. So, double check the documentation and remove your Java code to init log4j2 and see if that works. Other than that, I don't think there's anything more I can say to help you. Hope it works for you.